# Visual studio 17 LINK: fatal error LNK 1104: cannot open file';.obj'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, openframeworks

[Screenshot of when I try to run the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS67b.png)

So, I'm fairly new to open frameworks and I am trying to load a 3D model. I try loading it up but it keeps telling me that it cannot open the .obj file. I haven't found any recent posts addressing this problem so I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm on VS 2017, but I believe my project is using 2015. My open frameworks are the most recent version as well.

Comment: Looks like you messed up your project settings. Does this happen on a clean "Hello World" application?

Comment: Nope. I even have another openframeworks project without any 3d model loading and it works fine. It seems to just be when i try to go get the .obj.